# Removing extra large generated images disables all crops

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, media-library, cropping

```
function filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['1536x1536']); // disable 2x medium-large size
    unset( $sizes['2048x2048']); // disable 2x large size
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'filter_image_sizes');
```

I check the uploads folder and only the original image is being added now. I check the docs and I don't think I see it removing all the crops because of it.

Am I doing something wrong? When removing those sizes, do I need to add back the default sizes?

Comment: Your code, as written, should work. Is this *exactly* how it's written in your plugin / theme, or have you simplified it to post here? If the latter, check your code to make sure that `return $sizes;` isn't in an `if()` somewhere where it's only returning sometimes.

Comment: @PatJ Hello! Yes it's exactly what is in the theme.  I ended having to loop through approved ones and unset what's not in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function ( $sizes ) {

$allowed = [ 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'medium_large' ];
foreach ( $sizes as $name => $size ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $name, $allowed ) ) {
        unset( $sizes[ $name ] );
    }
}


return $sizes;
} );
```

I ended up setting an array with the crops I would allow and then unset anything that wasn't there.